# how zookeper talk with kafka to know kafka is up

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we have with 3 kafka machine and 3 zookeper servers

while kafka machines are not co-hosted with zookeper server ( kafka are on different machines , OS is redhat version 7.x )

in order to get the brokers id , we do the following on the zookeper servers

```
cd /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-server/bin

./zkCli.sh

ls /brokers/ids
```

results should be the three brokers id's as

```
1011  1012  1013
```

my question is - in which way zookeper know that broker is up?

or to be more specific

which cli zookeper execute in order to identify that kafka broker is up ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zookeeper is basically a distributed key-value store. Upon startup, a Kafka broker connects to Zookeeper (using the `zookeeper.connect` setting) and create a znode (a key-value pair) with its own `broker.id` under `/brokers/ids`. Kafka brokers then stay connected to Zookeeper while they are running.

The znode is created as "Ephemeral" (this is a feature of Zookeeper). It means that Zookeeper will delete it if the broker disconnects.

This way, Zookeeper knows at any time which brokers are alive (it does not necessarily mean the broker is healthy!). This is used by brokers to discover the other brokers in a cluster.

Comment: Dear Mickael , I will tell you why I asked this question , in our cluster sometimes one broker delete from /brokers/ids , in spite this broker is up on the kafka machine . so even we looked on the kafka logs we not see anything why broker isn't appears in /brokers/ids , can you give me direction to find the cause ot this problem ?

Comment: you said "delete it if the broker disconnects." , how to find the reason for this disconnecting ?   ( +1 )

Comment: It's the broker's job to connect to Zookeeper and keep its connection alive. So I'd start by checking the broker logs.

Comment: yes I know , but in broker log - server.log , we not see any Singh for this situation

Comment: what is interesting is that disconnected happens after ~ 1 day , do you feel that is realted to network problem ?

Comment: It's possible but it's impossible to tell without more data. Also at this point, it's a different question altogether.

Comment: regarding to your comment - I post another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52599185/java-io-ioexception-connection-to-kafka-via-port-6667-failed