# java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka VIA port 6667 failed at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.awaitReady

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have 3 kafka machines and 3 zookper machines

kafka machines are separated from the zookeper machines , and all machines are with OS - redhat 7.x

under `/var/log/kafka` we can see the following , `java.io.IOException` that displayed in `server.log`

```
               at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
[2018-10-07 07:42:13,342] WARN [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1007], Error in fetch kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread$FetchRequest@407ac4e4 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka03.hfge.com:6667 (id: 1007 rack: null) failed
               at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.awaitReady$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:83)
               at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingReady$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:93)
               at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:248)
               at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:238)
               at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:42)
               at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:118)
               at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:103)
               at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
[2018-10-07 07:42:13,551] WARN [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1002], Error in fetch kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread$FetchRequest@2f9f8ecd (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka07.hfge.com:6667 (id: 1002 rack: null) failed
               at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.awaitReady$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:83)
               at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingReady$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:93)
               at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:248)
               at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:238)
               at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:42)
               at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:118)
               at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:103)
               at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
[2018-10-07 07:42:15,343] WARN [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1007], Error in fetch kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread$FetchRequest@4dafd0d9 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka03.hfge.com:6667 (id: 1007 rack: null) failed
               at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.awaitReady$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:83)
               at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingReady$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:93)
               at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:248)
               at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:238)
               at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:42)
               at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:118)
               at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:103)
               at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
[2018-10-07 07:42:15,552] WARN [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1002], Error in fetch kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread$FetchRequest@5ce51081 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka07.hfge.com:6667 (id: 1002 rack: null) failed
```

additional with this , we also have a problem that kafka disconnected from the zookeeper after some time , 
this means that the broker id deleted from the zookeeper ( from zoo session /brokers/ids )

```
cd /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-server/bin

./zkCli.sh

ls /brokers/ids
```

any idea how to find the cause of

```
java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka03.hfge.com:6667
```

Comment: From Ambari, can you set the kafka log4j options to DEBUG?

Comment: I will try , and I will restart the kafka broker , do you want to look on the log after that ?

Comment: Yes, please update the new log after you edit the file and restart the broker that is having these warnings

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when the `inter.broker.protocol.version` is not updated correctly. To resolve this issue, update the `inter.broker.protocol.version` and restart the brokers one by one as described in the [Documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade).

Comment: dear @Giorgos , I get lost in the document , can you please be more specific what need to do in order to update the inter.broker.protocol.version?

Comment: Have you recently upgraded to Kafka 2.0.0?

Comment: no we have kafka version -  0.10.1  ( HDP version - 2.6.4 & spark - 2.2. )

Comment: so in case we not upgrade the kafka , then dose your answer still relevant?